# jqgrid getRowData returns null

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I have the code below:

```
$buttonoptions = array("#pager", 
    array(
        "caption" => "Select Product",
        "onClickButton" => "js: function() {
            var selr = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            var kelr = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getRowData', 'product_cat_id');
            if(selr) { 
                alert('grid.php?advice=' + selr + kelr); 
            } else {
                alert('Please Select a Product!');
                return false;
            }
        }"
    )
);
```

I successfully got the row ID in the following way:

```
var selr = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
```

But couldn't get the data of the selected row's `product_cat_id` column.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You use `getRowData` in a wrong way. Try

```
var kelr = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getCell', selr, 'product_cat_id');
```

or

```
var rowData = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getRowData', selr);    
var kelr = rowData.product_cat_id;
```

instead of

```
var kelr = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getRowData','product_cat_id');
```

Comment: Yet another helpful answer by @Oleg. I think it must be that the official jQgrid site is too hard to search / read.  I always seem to find what I'm looking for on StackOverflow rather than the jQgrid docs site.

Comment: @Brian L: Thanks! I do my best to help other. You are welcome!

Comment: @Oleg: Can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740258/jqgrid-select-checkbox. I am trying to find the best way of doing it. Thanks