# jqgrid get hidden column value with getRowData

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

I've checked [the jqgrid documentation page](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods), and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758915/jquery-and-jqgrid-retrieve-data-from-row), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285282/jqgrid-gridcomplete-getrowdata-get-row-cell-value-from-array) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179191/jqgrid-getrowdata-returns-null) but none of them answers my problem.

I have a jqgrid with the inline navigator (the buttons at the bottom left of the grid that allow adding/editing rows) displayed.

The grid has a hidden column, with the name *hidden_col*.

I would like to make the following - **When the user selects a row and tries to delete it**, the javascript makes **an alert** - which **shows the value of hidden_col** for the selected row.

For this, I have the following code

```
$("#myjqgrid").jqGrid('navGrid',"#myjqgrid_pager",
    {}, //options
    {}, // edit options
    {}, // add options
    {   mtype:"POST",
        reloadAfterSubmit:true,     //Reload data after deleting
        onclickSubmit: function(rowid)
        {           
          var rowData = $('#broadcast_table').jqGrid('getRowData', rowid);
          alert(rowData);
        }
    }, // del options
    {} // search options);
    );
```

The alert returns "[Object object]". How can I get the value of *hidden_col*?

I tried adding

```
var col_value = rowData.hidden_col;
```

And

```
var col_value = rowData['hidden_col'];
```

But both return *undefined*.

I checked the value in rowid - it is correct. I also know that hidden_col has a value for each row.

What can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was not using the parameter "rowid" as I should.

Here is the code, which I replaced in the first post, that does what I want:

```
onclickSubmit: function(){
                        var selected_row = $('#myjqgrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                        var rowdata = $('#myjqgrid').getRowData(selected_row);

                        alert(rowdata.hidden_col);
                         }
```